# Composition of homotopy classes with self-maps of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Are there some general rules/formulas on the relation between the homotopy class $[f]\in \pi_i(S^n)$ and the homotopy class of the
composition 
$S^i\stackrel{a}{\to} S^i\stackrel{f}{\to}S^n\stackrel{b}{\to}S^n$
where $a,b$ are maps of degree $d_a,d_b$ respectively? I think that composition with $a$ always multiplies $[f]$ by $d_a$, but composition with $b$ seems to be harder. Is  $[b\circ f]$ always a multiple of $[f]$?

Apparently, if $f: S^3\to S^2$ is the Hopf map, the homotopy class of the composition is $(d_a \times d_b^2) [f]$ ([see this book](https://books.google.cz/books?id=HY2DAwAAQBAJ&vq=hopf%20invariant&dq=composition%20of%20Hopf%20Fibration%20and%20degree%202%20map&hl=cs&source=gbs_navlinks_s), p. 205).
In the stable dimension range, however, composition with $b$ seems only to multiply $[f]$ by $d_b$, if I understand [this wikipedia paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Ring_structure) correctly (supercommutativity).

Comment: obviously, $[f\circ a]=d_a\cdot [f]$, and what about $b$?..

Comment: Andrey Ryabichev I agree that this part is obvious, but could you give me a hint for $b$? Thanks

Comment: i don't know. i think, in case $n<i\le2n-1$ it will be $d_b^2\cdot[f]$ for the same reason as in case Hopf fibration.

Comment: Andrey, I know it is a stupid question, but maybe you could comment on the Hopf case a bit, I don't understand that situation either and only found the result as an "exercise" in a book...

Comment: Your reading is correct; in the stable range, composition with $b$ is just multiplication by $d_b$.  In the unstable range I doubt there is much you can say in general (in particular, I doubt $[b\circ f]$ is always a multiple of $[f]$), but I don't know the details of these computations.  Probably these compositions are written down for small values of $i$ and $n$ somewhere in Toda's book _Composition methods in homotopy groups of spheres_.

Answer (score 1):

(this is not a full answer, but for comments it's too long)

For given (smooth) map $f:S^3\to S^2$ if you take two non-critical values $p,q\in S^2$, then linking number of $f^{-1}(p)$ with $f^{-1}(q)$ equals to degree of $f$. Maybe, something similar occurs in case $i=2n-1$ for all $n$.

And when you take a suspension of the diagrams 
$S^i\stackrel{a}{\to} S^i\stackrel{f}{\to}S^n\stackrel{b}{\to}S^n$,
for stable dimensions $i,n$ answer will be the same, because of map $\pi_i(S^n)\to\pi_{i+1}(S^{n+1})$ being surjective and equalities $d_{\Sigma a}=d_a$, $d_{\Sigma b}=d_b$.

Comment: Thanks for  the linking number argument, now I understand at least the Hopf case. As for the stable dimension range, I just read the wikipedia page and doesn't the alleged ring-graded-commutativity of stable homotopy ring suggest that the result is linear in both a and b in the stable range? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Ring_structure

Comment: @PeterFranek, yes, supercommutativity lets us change $a,b$ to $a',b'$ such that $d_{b'}=1$ and $d_{a'}=d_a d_b$, that makes obviously an answer. but i don't understand where is a mistake in my arguments for $i=2n-1$.